# Empty numeric vectors after loop

Tags: r

I have a list of 300+ tables in a list and I'm trying to count the amount of times there are no rows in a table.

So the loop I am running in order to do so is:

```
> while (i < 333) {
  b <- b + (nrow(allInfo[[i]])==0)
  i <- i + 1
 }
```

I have set i to 1 and have tried setting b to both 0 and also `b <- vector("numeric", 1L)` and tried setting it to "integer". At the end of the loop b ends up having the value "numeric (empty)" and I have not been able to figure this out.

Could I please get some help on why this is the case?

Comment: I guess some element of `allInfo` is not a data.frame, maybe NULL, so `nrow(NULL)` is `integer(0)`, and any number plus `integer(0)` is `numeric(0)`. Try using `NROW()` instead, or filtering out non-data.frames `allInfo <- allInfo[!sapply(allInfo, is, "data.frame"))]`

Answer (score 7):

It seems you might want something as simple as

```
sum(sapply(allInfo, nrow) == 0)
```

This grabs the number of rows of each element in the list, returned as an atomic vector.  Then we can determine the number of those that equal zero and sum the resulting logical vector (since the integer representation of `TRUE` is `1`).

Comment: That's great thanks so much. There are so many functions I'm busy learning that I kind of skipped over the s and lapply functions. By the way, the code I had above works, but the last entry of the file I was reading didn't pull through so it didn't work. This is far better and cleaner though and very useful so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
while (i < 333) {
  b <- b + (nrow(as.data.frame(allInfo[[i]]))==0)
  i <- i + 1
 }
```

Rich's answer is the best.